# Единый дизайн android-приложения

Tags: android, design

**Добрые день!**

Каким образом можно задать единый дизайн для всего приложения? Я имею в виду для всех Layout`ов во всех View. Как такое можно сделать? Ведь в функциональном приложении может присутствовать несколько View и даже десятки Layout`ов...не делать же одно и то же десятки раз!

**Спасибо!**

Comment: Переопределить рендер? Но вообще Вы с этим аккуратно - так недолго и дойти до того что "не писать же букву 'a' десятки раз в коде!" :-)

Comment: Ну просто интересно, вдруг такое правда возможно реализовать - некоторая рутинная работа отпадет.

Comment: метка "дизигн" доставила :))))

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы дизайн экранов приложения выглядел консистентным нужно описывать тему приложения в отдельном ресурсе (к примеру, в themes.xml), а стили базовых элементов и лайаутов в styles.xml. Тема применяется ко всему приложению в манифесте, стили лайаутов уже в файлах верстки.
Вам не нужно будет каждый раз описывать стиль лайаута, достуточно будет указать

```
style="@style/MyLayoutStyle"
```

Также сильно упрощает написание стилей возможность их наследования, как от системных, так и от своих, описанных ранее

Comment: Спасибо. Это хороший подход)